# How to Mock out AWS SDK for Go call

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, go, request, mocking

I am writing a unit test for a function that uses the AWS SDK for Go to get a secret from the AWS Secrets Manager:

**main.go**

```
//Helper function to get secret from AWS Secret Manager
func getAWSSecrets(svc secretsmanageriface.SecretsManagerAPI) (secretMap map[string]string, err error) {
    //Get secret config values
    req, resp := svc.GetSecretValueRequest(&secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
        SecretId: aws.String("my/secret/string"),
    })

    err = req.Send()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

 ...
}
```

In order to test this, I need to create a mock AWS Secret Manager Client.  I've set up the basic skeleton of how that will work:

**main_test.go**

```
type MockSecretsManagerClient struct {
  secretsmanageriface.SecretsManagerAPI
} 

func (m *MockSecretsManagerClient) GetSecretValueRequest(input *secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput) (req *request.Request, resp *secretsmanager.GetSecretValueOutput){
  // Confused on how to mock out the returned `req`
}


// tests getAWSSecrets
func (suite *ServerTestSuite) TestGetAWSSecrets() {
    //Setup test 
  mockSvc := &MockSecretsManagerClient{}
  req, resp := getAWSSecrets(mockSvc)
}
```

I'm running into trouble trying to mock the returned request from `GetSecretValueRequest`.  Furthermore, once I mock this request, I'm not sure how to handle mocking `req.Send()`. Is there a simple way to do this? Or are there any good examples of someone doing this?

Comment: What trouble specifically are you running into?

Comment: @Adrian I'm new to Go, so I have absolutely no idea how to start mocking the request that is returned from `GetSecretValueRequest`

Comment: To be able to mock the request as well you'll have to define an interface for it, just like there is an interface for the manger you'll need one for the request. If the sdk does not provide one you'll have to define it yourself. Here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/muEuHe_Vesm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find the service in the 
["AWS SDK for Go API Reference."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/)

Then look up the API call.  Your call is here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/secretsmanager/#SecretsManager.GetSecretValueRequest

The prototype for the API call is

```
func (c *SecretsManager) GetSecretValueRequest(input *GetSecretValueInput) (req *request.Request, output *GetSecretValueOutput)
```

So it returns a request.Request and a GetSecretValueOutput

The two output items are structs and they are linked in the documentation.  The mock should return those two items in the same way ie

```
func (m *MockSecretsManagerClient) GetSecretValueRequest(input *secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput) (req *request.Request, resp *secretsmanager.GetSecretValueOutput) {

    req = new(request.Request)
    r := new(http.Response)
    r.Status = "200 OK"
    r.Status = 200
    req.HTTPRequest = r
    resp.SecretString = new(String("this is the dummy value"))

    return
}
```

If you need the mock values to be mock like "real" data from a live API service then write a quick program to do a call and `Printf` the return values using `"%#v"` format.  This should give you most of what you need